# Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and sass. Nodejs with grunt.

app.sss

```
$icon-font-path: "/bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
$fa-font-path: "/bower_components/font-awesome/fonts";
$header-height: 50px;

@import 'bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
...
...
...
```

Error:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
      ╷
    4 │ @import 'bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap'
```

I've tried using `~ no $icon-font-path`, tried to put the relative path, and it didn't work.

Any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: By default Sass will include the content of the file being imported in place of the @import statement, but there are times when Sass will compile to a CSS import rule. In other words you’ll end up with an import in the .css file instead of the code in the referenced file. Reference at : https://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-the-import-directive/

Answer (score 0):

So there could be multiple errors:

1. Is the Path to the stylesheet correct ?
2. Is the filename correct ?
3. Do you have to put a "/" before the path like "/bootstrap-sass-official/..." ?

Try this out and look for the result :)

Comment: Yes, the way is right. This project has been in operation for 2 years. Now I need to edit some things, got the git project, used npm install, and when I run to test the project, this error comes up.